# Exception in selenium WebDriver : b.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I tried to find an input element by the code below

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=\"passengers[0].passengerName\"]")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

selenium thrown the following error..

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: b.addEventListener is not a function
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:45'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.38-13-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Session ID: e713ccdc-dc05-40a1-923a-8ee51cfa525b
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=16.0.2, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:533)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:302)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:379)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:407)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:294)
        at irctcticketbooking.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: b.addEventListener is not a function
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:45'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.38-13-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:7185)
        at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///tmp/anonymous8377906034759035727webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:6821)
        at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///tmp/anonymous8377906034759035727webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8245)
        at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///tmp/anonymous8377906034759035727webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8260)
        at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///tmp/anonymous8377906034759035727webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10222)
        at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///tmp/anonymous8377906034759035727webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10227)
        at <anonymous class>.<anonymous method>(file:///tmp/anonymous8377906034759035727webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10167)
```

I've tried with the element id, name, css and xpath. Nothing helped in getting rid of this exception.

Source html file : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/345966710/A.html
Test java code : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/345966710/Test.java

Comment: You would need to share the piece of html u are trying to interact with..

Comment: @niharika_neo source of the file attached.

Answer (score 0):

`findElementByName("passengers[0].passengerName").sendKeys("P1")`  works for me

Used java webdriver 2.25 with ff 16 - Windows

Tried with 2.28 as well.

Comment: You tried using java? I hope you tested the code with javascript. It's reproducible in Ubuntu and windows.

Comment: FYI i'm using selenium 2.28.0. What does this exception mean?

Comment: Can you show ur driver init code?  What does line number 119 in your main method contain?

Comment: Since i'm using using ubuntu there was no need to set any properties. I just used WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver() and the line at 119 is             driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=\"passengers[0].passengerName\"]")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxx");

Comment: I tested the same code in my friend's system as well. It generated the same error in FF 16.0.2. The previous line is         driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton0")).click(); I don't think it'll have any connections to this exception.

Comment: Have you tried with the one I have given as an answer?  I tried with this as well : By.cssSelector("input[name='passengers[0].passengerName']") which worked for me.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your setup. This is what i did. Downloaded java 2.28 from the website. Added jars in Netbeans and tried to run the file. This exception occurs in windows 7 also. So this might not be any platform specific bug.

Comment: :) wrong with my setup?  you didn't answer 2 of my quesionts "Have you tried with the one I have given as an answer?" I have removed the \" from ur cssselector and replaced with ' ..have you tried with thtat? By.cssSelector("input[name='passengers[0].passengerName']"

Comment: Sorry @niharika_neo yes i tried with what you suggested and by id, xpath etc., Nothing did the trick for me.

Comment: May i send the code to you so that you'll run and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name*='0'][name*='passengerName']")).sendKeys("test");
```

Comment: @santhosh Again got the same exception. Source html file and the java code sample is attached. If u test you'll see by yourself.